# ResponseStatusException is never returned back to user

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, exception

I've got a Spring Boot Rest API that does some validation filtering before allowing the request through to the requested method. When it makes it to the requested endpoint, I do some validation on the data sent to the server, and want to return a BAD REQUEST response if the data isn't properly formatted. However trying to throw Springs ResponseStatusException doesn't work, instead it always returns a 403 Forbidden and I have no idea why.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
JWTUtility jwtUtility;
@Autowired
UserRepository repository;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtUtility, repository))
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users");
}
}
```

.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@Slf4j
public class UserController {
private final UserRepository repository;
private final Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

UserController(UserRepository repository, Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, JWTUtility jwtUtility) {
    this.repository = repository;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    this.jwtUtility = jwtUtility;
}

@PostMapping
User create(@RequestBody User user) {
    if (user.getFirstName() == null || user.getFirstName().isEmpty()
            || user.getLastName() == null || user.getLastName().isEmpty()
            || user.getEmail() == null || user.getEmail().isEmpty()
            || user.getDisplayName() == null || user.getDisplayName().isEmpty()
            || user.getPassword() == null || user.getPassword().isEmpty()) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "First name, last name, email, display name, and password must be provided when creating a new user.");
    }
    if (repository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()) != null) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "A user with that email already exists");
    }
    if (repository.findByDisplayName(user.getDisplayName()) != null) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "A user with that display name already exists");
    }

    user.setId(0);
    user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

    repository.save(user);

    return user;
}
}
```

I would expect the bad request to make it back to the user with the description I provided. Is Spring intercepting this somewhere? And how can I stop it.

Comment: Can you print the stack exceptions of your rest service ?

Comment: That's the strange thing, it isn't generating a stack trace anywhere. Once it hits my throw, it just returns a 403.

Comment: Commenting out `@EnableWebSecurity` causes it to never hit my endpoint, and instead just returns a 401 Unauthorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with the security configuration, while I had the `/users` endpoint ignored in the web security configuration, allowing the request through to the method, apparently throwing an exception within that method caused the http security to get involved and intercept it.

Therefore, changing my http security to look like this,

```
http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users").permitAll()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtUtility, repository))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

solved the issue. It's strange that it behaves like this, since if the request is successful and I don't need to throw an exception, the user object returns just fine. It seems that throwing the exception caused it to not only pay attention to the web security but also the http security.